# Detect Duplicate Items in DataFlow

Tags: c#, multithreading, tpl-dataflow, dataflow

I've been building out a service that processes files using a `Queue<string>` object to manage the items.

```
public partial class BasicQueueService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly EventWaitHandle completeHandle = 
      new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "ThreadCompleters");

    public BasicQueueService()
    {
        QueueManager = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public bool Stopping { get; set; }

    private Queue<string> QueueManager { get; }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Stopping = false;

        ProcessFiles();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        Stopping = true;
    }

    private void ProcessFiles()
    {
        while (!Stopping)
        {
            var count = QueueManager.Count;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //Check the Stopping Variable again.
                if (Stopping) break;

                var fileName = QueueManager.Dequeue();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) || !File.Exists(fileName)) 
                       continue;

                Console.WriteLine($"Processing {fileName}");

                Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        DoWork(fileName);
                    })
                    .ContinueWith(ThreadComplete);
            }
            if (Stopping) continue;

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for thread to finish, or 1 minute.");
            completeHandle.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
            completeHandle.Reset();
        }
    }

    partial void DoWork(string fileName);

    private void ThreadComplete(Task task)
    {
        completeHandle.Set();
    }

    public void AddToQueue(string file)
    {
        //Called by FileWatcher/Manual classes, not included for brevity.
        lock (QueueManager)
        {
            if (QueueManager.Contains(file)) return;

            QueueManager.Enqueue(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Whilst researching how to limit the number of threads on this (I've tried a manual class with an incrementing `int`, but there's an issue where it doesn't decrement properly in my code), I came across [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604.aspx), which seems like its a better fit for what I'm trying to achieve - specifically, it allows me to let the framework handle threading/queueing, etc.

This is now my service:

```
public partial class BasicDataFlowService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly ActionBlock<string> workerBlock;

    public BasicDataFlowService()
    {
        workerBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(file => DoWork(file), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32
        });
    }

    public bool Stopping { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Stopping = false;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        Stopping = true;
    }

    partial void DoWork(string fileName);

    private void AddToDataFlow(string file)
    {
        workerBlock.Post(file);
    }
}
```

This works well. However, I want to ensure that a file is only ever added to the `TPL DataFlow` once. With the `Queue`, I can check that using `.Contains()`. Is there a mechanism that I can use for `TPL DataFlow`?

Comment: Whatever is consuming and submitting the files has the responsibility of not posting them twice. If your reading  files from directory you could tag them, or cache the path as @VMAtm suggested. But if users or otherwise clients are submitting them you'll need to treat the processes as a job. Where each file represents a single job with a single result.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with `Queue` works only if file goes into your service twice in a small period of time. If it came again in, say, few hours, queue will not contain it, as you `Dequeue` it from there.

If this solution is expected, then you may use a [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) to store file paths being already handled, like this:

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;

private static object _lock = new object();

private void AddToDataFlow(string file)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        if (MemoryCache.Default.Contains(file))
        {
            return;
        }

        // no matter what to put into the cache
        MemoryCache.Default[file] = true;
    // we can now exit the lock
    }

    workerBlock.Post(file);
}
```

However, if your application must run for a long time (which service is intended to do), you'll eventually run out of memory. In that case you probably need to store your file paths in database or something, so even after restarting the service your code will restore the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it inside of `DoWork`.

You have to save in `Hash` already works items and check current filename doesn't exist in hash.